Google Sheet to updatable/live JSON
I need to get a live/updatable JSON file from a Google Sheet
From here https://gist.github.com/ronaldsmartin/47f5239ab1834c47088e
I get code for creating a live/updatable JSON
I have copied the file to a .gs file in my Google sheet.
and it is used like so:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzGvKKUIaqsMuCj7-A2YRhR-f7GZjl4kSxSN1YyLkS01_CfiyE/exec?id=<spreadsheet key>sheet=<sheet name on spreadsheet>

But I can not figueout how to the point the URL to my own copy not the github copy?
Thanks
/**
 * Main method is called when the script receives a GET request.
 * Receives the request, generates and returns the output.
 */
function doGet(request) {
  // Get request params.
  var sheetKey  = request.parameters.id;
  var sheetName = request.parameters.sheet;
  var callback  = request.parameters.callback;
  var headerRow = request.parameters.header;
  var startRow  = request.parameters.startRow;
    
  // Parse the spreadsheet.
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetKey);
  var keys = getHeaderRowKeys_(spreadsheet, sheetName, headerRow);
  var data = readData_(spreadsheet, sheetName, keys, startRow);
  
  // Filter for matching terms.
  data = data.filter(function(entry) {
    var matches = true;
    for (var k in keys) {
      var key = keys[k].replace(/\s+/g, '_');
      var searchTerm = request.parameters[key];
      // Use the string form of the value since params are strings by default
      if (searchTerm != undefined)
        matches = matches && ("" + entry[key] == searchTerm);
    }
    // Matches is true iff all params are undefined or all values for keys match.
    return matches;
  });
  
  // Write and return the response.
  var response = JSON.stringify({ records: data });
  var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
  if (callback == undefined) {
    // Serve as JSON
    output.setContent(response).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } else {
    // Serve as JSONP
    output.setContent(callback + "(" + response + ")")
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
  }
  return output;
}

/**
 * Get a row in a spreadsheet as an Object, using the values in the header row as
 * keys and the corresponding row values as the values.
 * 
 * @param spreadsheet Spreadsheet object housing the sheet and header
 * @param sheetName Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet with the data
 * @param properties Optional array of keys to use for the row values. Default is the first row.
 * @param startRowNum Optional top row number of the rows to parse. The default is
 * the second row (i.e., below the header).
 */
function readData_(spreadsheet, sheetName, properties, startRowNum) {
  if (typeof properties == "undefined") {
    properties = getHeaderRowKeys_(spreadsheet, sheetName);
  }
  
  var rows = getDataRows_(spreadsheet, sheetName, startRowNum);
  var data = [];
  for (var r = 0, l = rows.length; r < l; r++) {
    var row = rows[r];
    var record = {};
    for (var p in properties) {
      record[properties[p]] = row[p];
    }
    data.push(record);
  }
  return data;
}

/**
 * Parse spreadsheet data as an array of Javascript Objects.
 *
 * @param spreadsheet Spreadsheet object with the data to get
 * @param sheetName Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet with the data
 * @param startRowNum Optional top row number of the rows to parse. The default is
 * the second row (i.e., below the header).
 */
function getDataRows_(spreadsheet, sheetName, startRowNum) {
  if (typeof startRowNum == "undefined") startRowNum = 2;
  
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  return sheet.getRange(startRowNum, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
}

/**
 * Return the array of keys used in the header, replacing whitespace with underscores.
 * 
 * @param spreadsheet Spreadsheet object housing the sheet and header
 * @param sheetName Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet whose header values to get
 * @param rowNum Optional exact row number of the header. Default is the first row.
 */
function getHeaderRowKeys_(spreadsheet, sheetName, rowNum) {
  if (typeof rowNum == "undefined") rowNum = 1;
  return getHeaderRow_(spreadsheet, sheetName, rowNum).map(function(value) { 
    return value.replace(/\s+/g, '_');
  });
}

/**
 * Get the values in the header row of the given sheet in a spreadsheet
 * 
 * @param spreadsheet Spreadsheet object housing the sheet and header
 * @param sheetName Name of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet whose header values to get
 * @param rowNum Exact row number of the header.
 */
function getHeaderRow_(spreadsheet, sheetName, rowNum) {
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  return sheet.getRange(rowNum, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
}


Have you tried to Deploy it?

What kind of data are you expecting to get?

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand But I can not figueout how to the point the URL to my own copy not the github copy?. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

I do not know how to add my own API to the code, so it uses my version in my Google sheet App Script

Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between I do not know how to add my own API to the code, so it uses my version in my Google sheet App Script and But I can not figueout how to the point the URL to my own copy not the github copy? and your expected input and output situations. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Deploy it. Top right button.
